# AutoMapper suggestion required

Tags: automapper, automapper-2

I have below classes

```
class Contact  
{  
  string FirstName;  
  string LastName;  
  List<Phone> ContactNumbers;  
}

class Phone  
{  
  string Number;  
  PhoneType Type;  
}  

enum PhoneType  
{  
  Home, Work, Fax
}  

class Source
{
  Contact Agent;
  Contact Customer;
}

class Destination  
{  
  string AgentFirstName;  
  string AgentLastName;  
  string AgentPhoneNumber1;  
  string AgentPhoneNumber2;  
  string AgentPhoneNumber3;  
  PhoneType AgentPhoneType1;  
  PhoneType AgentPhoneType2;  
  PhoneType AgentPhoneType3; 

  string CustomerFirstName;  
  string CustomerLastName;  
  string CustomerPhoneNumber1;  
  string CustomerPhoneNumber2;  
  string CustomerPhoneNumber3;  
  PhoneType CustomerPhoneType1;  
  PhoneType CustomerPhoneType2;  
  PhoneType CustomerPhoneType3;  

}
```

I want to do auto-map from **Source** to **Destination** class.  The challenge I see is to convert the list of contact numbers into independent fields in destination class.  Can anyone please suggest the ways?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably easiest to do a custom mapping function, which keeps things simple and readable:

```
CreateMap<Contact, Destination>().ConvertUsing(c => MapContactToDestination(c));

Destination MapContactToDestination(Contact c)
{
    //logic here for handling conversion
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for missing clarity... I have amended the original post to give correct picture on what I require. Thanks for re-look.  I also feel that writing logic using Resolver or ConvertUsing would be almost equivalent to do manual mapping of each field.  I would like to see if there are any other options also available...

Comment: There is no way to do this with a fully automatic mapping, for such a case it is just so much easier and quicker to do a custom conversion.